# using signlar with bot framework

Tags: c#, signalr, botframework

I am creating a live chat on top of my bot framework , so I am hosting an administration portal and a bot solution projects in the same solution ( two different projects )

I am trying to send the message received to the bot to signalr hub to send it later to the live chat window , but the method is not being invoked

here is my code:

```
 if (currentData.CurrentConversation != null && currentData.CurrentConversation.conversationchatmode == agentMode.conversationchatmodeid)
                        {  

                            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ControlPanel.ChatHub>();
                            hubContext.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message.Text);
                            var endResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                            return endResponse;
                        }
```

and this is the javascript code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#btnSend").click();
        }
    });
    $(function () {
        debugger;

        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
            // Html encode display name and message. 
            //var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();

        };

        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {
            debugger;
               var messageTobeAdded = "<div class='incoming_msg'>" +

                    "<div class='outgoing_msg'>" +
                    " <div class='sent_msg'> <p>" +


                    message +  

                    '</p>' +
                    "<span class='time_date'>" + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + " </span> " +
                    '</div>'
                    + '</div>'
                + '</div>';
                 $('#msgBox').append(messageTobeAdded);
        };
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#btnSend').click(function (e) {
                debugger;
                var encodedMsg = $('#txtMessage').val();
                // Add the message to the page. 
                var messageTobeAdded = "<div class='incoming_msg'>" +

                    "<div class='outgoing_msg'>" +
                    " <div class='sent_msg'> <p>" +


                    encodedMsg +

                    '</p>' +
                    "<span class='time_date'>" + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + " </span> " +
                    '</div>'
                    + '</div>'
                    + '</div>';
                $('#msgBox').append(messageTobeAdded);
                // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                //Getting hidden field values
                debugger;
                var hfBotId = $("#" + '<%= hfBotId.ClientID %>').val();
                var hfBotName = $("#" + '<%= hfBotName.ClientID %>').val();
                var hfcustomerName = $("#" + '<%= hfcustomerName.ClientID %>').val();
                var hfcustomerrecepeintId = $("#" + '<%= hfcustomerrecepeintId.ClientID %>').val();
                chat.server.send(hfBotId , hfBotName , hfcustomerName , hfcustomerrecepeintId, encodedMsg);
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                $('#txtMessage').val('').focus();
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#msgBox').scrollTop($('#msgBox')[0].scrollHeight);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

these methods are working fine if i am using the chat inside the same window , i mean i can send live chat messages and receive it , but i am unable to send a message from the bot side to the live chat

Comment: I'm unclear of your description of the solution structure. Is your bot a separate web application project from the web application project that represents the admin portal? Or is your bot project just bot controllers and then you host those via the admin portal web application?

Comment: Yes , they are two both different web applications but they are in the same solution in visual studio , so i managed to add a reference for the portal inside the bot web application

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I understand your set up correctly, they're two different web applications. This would mean that the SignalR hub instances will be completely unique within each running application. Meaning that the portal application will be hosting the "real" hub instances that your actual clients are connecting to, but then, in your bot application, you're trying to use the hub context there and those will be instances of their own that have no clients attached to them.

The simplest option would be to host the bot in the portal application itself. This would ensure it is accessing the exact hub instances as the portal. The downside to this approach is you'd be overloading your application with multiple responsibilities (e.g. now you're running the bot in your portal app).

The next option would be to provide an extra "backend" REST API in the form of a controller in your portal application that is specifically designed to allow the bot to trigger the events you know it needs to and can be secured specifically so that only clients like the bot can call it (e.g. using a shared key).

A third option would be to have your bot become a *client* of the actual SignalR application that's being hosted by the portal itself. This would keep you to a single protocol and communication mechanism (vs introducing a controller) and, again, the bot would just authenticate itself specially so that it can trigger events within the hubs that basic users cannot.

Comment: How would you go about implementing the third option?